# Kuman 7 inch LCD touchscreen compatible with Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero, touchscreen, lcd

Does anyone know if this [Kuman 7" TFT LCD Capacitive Touch Screen](http://www.kumantech.com/kuman-7quot-tft-lcd-capacitive-touch-screen-hdmi-800480-for-raspberry-pi-3-2-model-b-rpi-1-b-a-bb-black-pc-sc7b_p0222.html) is compatible with the Raspberry Pi Zero?  On the website it says *Raspberry Pi 3 2 Model B, RPi 1 B+ A* but why wouldn't it work with the Zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen itself looks like it work just fine.  However, the neither the HDMI cable nor the USB cable that accompany the unit will work with Pi Zero.

Comment: I assume you simply mean you still need a mini-HDMI to HDMI adapter and micro-USB to USB OTG adapter but otherwise would work.

Comment: @OpenUserX03 : Correct.

Answer (score 4):

It's working with my zero. However you will need to adjust the settings to use the entire screen, just researching that now.

The Kuman screen (which should come with the proper cable) is:
Kuman Capacitive 7" inch Touch Screen TFT LCD module HDMI 800x480 for Raspberry Pi 2 and RPi 1 Model B B+ BB BLACK SC7B

This page helped: [7-Inch-800x480 Display Kit(without Touch Screen) SKU:Z-0111](https://www.wiki.52pi.com/index.php?title=7-Inch-800x480_Display_Kit(without_Touch_Screen)_SKU:Z-0111)

The touch screen works on the latest Raspbian (19?)

- 864 x 480 x 24bit graphics content through SSD1963 controller

and my RPi settings in `/boot/config.txt`

<strike>hdmi_group=2</strike>
 <strike>hdmi_mode=14</strike>

or for exact screen dimensions (tested and working).

<strike>hdmi_group=2</strike>
 <strike>hdmi_mode=87</strike>
 <strike>hdmi_cvt=800 480 60</strike>

See [Video options in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

The LCD should come with the adapter (mine did, ordered off amazon from Kuman), but yes, as the Raspberry Pi Zero is mini HDMI and the Kuman LCD is regular HDMI, you need an adapter... However it does not just work. On boot up you will find Raspbian running in 4:3 when it should be 16:9 and the touch will be off. The settings above will get it working correctly on boot.

#### Update

I found the cd that came with the lcd. The config.txt lists these settings for the LCD.

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```